# Use id as key and name as value of the array

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to change the format of the mysql result...

```
[0] =>  
      [id]   => 1    
      [name] => King     
[1] =>  
      [id]   => 5
      [name] => Queen
```

To this format:

```
[1] => King
[5] => Queen
```

But I have no idea how to put the mysql result in such a format.

```
$teamSql   = "SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE  projectid = '1';
$teamQuery = mysql_query($teamSql);
$teamFetch= mysql_fetch_assoc($teamQuery);
// and now?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$teamSql   = "SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE  projectid = '1'";
$teamQuery = mysql_query($teamSql);
$teams = array();
while ($team = mysql_fetch_array($teamQuery))
{
    $teams[$team['id']] = $team['name'];
}
```

Comment: Simple but ingenious. Thanks! Is it necessary to declare the array? or can you skip the '$teams = array();' line? I've never found out.

Comment: If you don't declare it and the query ends up returning nothing, $teams wouldn't be an array. That means using functions like in_array or even a foreach would return an error, since $teams is in fact not an array.

Answer (score -1):

For showing result in PHP,

Use foreach loop

like foreach ($teamFetch as $teamFetched){

echo $teamFetched;

}

thats it..

Comment: you can rearrange echo as whatever you want